# Java Compiling/running slow in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, performance

So I have an issue that I can't seem to fix. No matter the size of my projects, I've always compiled in under a second or two at maximum. Now since two days ago, it starts compiling and the red "Terminate" button lights up. It takes about 5-6 seconds before it actually opens up and runs.
I've tried new workspaces and just a main function class to print a simple string, still same slowness.

I've tried resetting all themes and options, I've tried turning off ALL validation, I've tried reinstalling Eclipse with two different versions, and finally I've mixed with parameters in eclipse.ini such as giving it more RAM.

Possible reasons behind the slowness (that I can think of):
-Corrupted file (possibly in some appdata folder or the likes since root is redone upon reinstall)
-Upgrade to Windows 10 (however it worked fine for weeks before this happened)

Specs if needed:
-Windows 10 Home 64 bit
-i7-4820k CPU @3,85GHz overclock (small overclocking that's np with internal ac)
-16GB RAM
-GTX 780

Checked around for some help but found none.
Any at all is very much appreciated, thanks!

Edit:
It's a graphical issue, still unknown if it's related to Java or Eclipse.

Comment: Did you have a look in the Eclipse .log file?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling Eclipse?

Comment: "I've tried reinstalling Eclipse with two different versions"

I'll check the log, you're talking about the one that generates upon errors?

Comment: What shows in the tasks running stack? It should say "Waiting for XYZ to finish" if there is something hanging it.

Comment: @Compass
Sorry, where do I find this? I only see the percentage loading for a split second, then it just stays at the lit up red terminate button without any messages, then after like 5-6 seconds the program opens up.

Comment: Window -> Show View -> Other (Progress). When you run, it should list what is blocking execution, if any.

Comment: @Compass
It all works fine, everything flashes by in a second, then says "No operations to display at this time."

Comment: Have you done a complete clean of the project prior to rebuilding?

Comment: @ManoDestra
Complete clean of everything, install, project, and workspace.

Comment: Okay so I've come down to it being a graphical issue. The consol prints thing normally if it's done separately, or before the creation of a window or a sort of display.
Still don't know if it's related to my monitor (tried on both), java itself, or eclipse. Same thing happens for all projects with some sort of display in use.

Comment: Bumping cause annoying problem :/

Comment: The problem decided to go away, so no help needed I guess. Might have had something to do with a Windows 10 update.

Comment: I have a similar long compile time on an old iMac with small files in Eclipse with Java: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376872/why-is-my-compile-time-in-eclipse-so-long-on-an-older-imac?noredirect=1#comment507982_376872